# Ansys Fluent Meshing and analysis

Tags: ansys

I am having a problem in the analysis of a pipe with an impeller.
I have designed a quarter pipe and I have divided the quarter pipe into 5 bodies for good meshing.
Now I need to develop a flow with the translational periodic condition by applying a pressure gradient.
But when I am applying periodic condition in fluent, it shows some errors. I am not able to select multi-face of inlet together as one periodic face.
I have tried to fuse these bodies together in fluent but wasn't successful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are better of asking this at the [ANSYS Student Community Forum](https://studentcommunity.ansys.com/).

For your issue, ensure that all your bodies are in a multi-body part. Have *all* the upstream faces in a single name selection and *all* downstream faces in a single name selection.

Answer (score 0):

The first checks for a periodic boundary condition is to make sure both the faces match each other. Otherwise fluent is unable to assign it as an infinitely long pipe. A fan in the middle of the pipe would also make this exercise futile!